# What is happening to Northwest Angle?

Tags: usa, canada, borders, covid-19

With the closure of the US-Canada border to all but essential traffic, does anyone know what is happening to [Northwest Angle](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/manitoba/northwest-angle-profile-1.4973625)?

Northwest Angle is a 300 square kilometer part of Michigan that is entirely surrounded by Canada. It has a population of about 120.

Does anyone know if the border between the two is kept open?

Comment: "It's not clear yet what happens to the dozens of people living on the Angle" [Minnesota news 18 March 2020](https://bringmethenews.com/minnesota-news/coronavirus-northern-border-with-canada-to-be-closed)

Comment: The same question could also be asked about [Point Roberts,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Roberts,_Washington) but I can't find any information about that yet either.

Comment: 10 times as many people live in [Point Roberts, WA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_Roberts,_Washington) in less than 5 sq mile. And I bet there are other odd places like that all over the world.

Comment: I suspect very strongly that residents of those places are much more likely to have "essential" needs to cross the border, and are consequently much more likely to be permitted to cross it.

Comment: From what I can gather northwest angle is not completely surrounded by, but you need a boat to reach the rest of the US without going through Canada.

Comment: I know you aren't, but to anyone else reading this: please don't try to travel there right now unless you absolutely must.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a rapidly-changing event. Have a read on the relevant governmental websites to answer your question. These will surely be correct, as well as up to date.

Comment: Are we closing all covid-19 related questions now?

Comment: @JoErNanO Stack Exchange allows for rapidly changing events - moderators can add a post notice (I see that has been put on this question), and answers can be edited.  All this needs is an answer that says things may change, and with the current known info at a point in time (with some links to the source).  Once new info comes to light the answer can be edited with that new info (and new references).  This would surely be preferable to closing every question!  I vote to reopen this question.